# How to send password set(reset link) laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I was trying to send a password reset link to my newly created user and had a hard time trying to find a solution. In case someone has the same issue here is what worked for me in Laravel 7.

Or is there a better way to handle all: add entry in password_resets table and send the notification?
Mail sending properly but i want to send password reset mail to user .Below is the my add controller

```
public function contactSave(Request $request)
    {

        $password = Hash::make($request->name);

        $validate = $request->validate([
                        'name' => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u',
                        'email' => 'email',
                        'phone' => 'digits:10',
                        'address' => 'required',
                        'country' => 'required',
                        'state' => 'required',
                        // 'comment' => 'required',
                        'organization' => 'required',
                        'captcha' => 'required|captcha'
                    ],
                    [
                'captcha.captcha' => 'Incorrect Captcha'
            ]
                );

        $user= new User;
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;     
        $user->password = $password;
        $user->save();


        $CustomerContact= new CustomerContact;

        // $CustomerContact->name = $request->name;
        // $CustomerContact->email = $request->email;
        $CustomerContact->phone = $request->phone;
        $CustomerContact->address = $request->address;
        $CustomerContact->user_id = $user->id;
        $CustomerContact->country_id = $request->country;
        $CustomerContact->state_id = $request->state;
        $CustomerContact->comment = $request->comment;
        $CustomerContact->organization = $request->organization;
        $CustomerContact->captcha = $request->captcha;

        $CustomerContact->save();

        $details = [
            'title' => 'Hi '.$request->name.'',
            'body' => 'Your account has been created successfully. Request you set your password with this link ???'
        ];
       
        \Mail::to($request->email)->send(new \App\Mail\ContactMail($details));

        return redirect('contacts')->with('success', 'User created successfully.');

        
    }
```

Anyone here to help me. After saving data in user and employee . I want send email with password reset link to that user id email($request->email).
GIve me simplest solution with kittle explation how to do this

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: @sta , No still not getting any Solution.

Answer (score 0):

if i correctly understood your problem you can create a route for example: `password/reset/user-code`
and send it in your email to every user.
you should create a random-code for every user when its created and put it in that link and send in your email.
when user click on that link it will come to your controller and you check that random-code in your database and find your user! and when you have your user you can show them your view for resetting password and save new password
that what i did for password reset before

Comment: Yes right i am using default auth .When user created mail send with url. When url open Password reset page will open with token and save to reset_password table. I am new in this. I am not getting how to create tokenid nd send link to user.

Comment: maybe this link would help you :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669965/laravel-password-reset-token

Comment: I know the tocken created but how i will send Welcome message with that password link?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean. when user clicked on that link, it goes to some function where you return your password-reset view. you can pass anything you want to that view

Comment: Actually i have doubt only how to send mail with that url with token. I am not getting that one

Comment: if you are using laravel default authentication service, it will do everything for you by itself

Comment: If you go through my above controller code. I am confused how to pass that url with token for password set (link) into mail. I am not getting that one. My mail going perfectly after create user. But I am not getting how to add password set into that. Yes I am using  laravel default authentication service.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to send some data (link or token or everything else) to your mail use this:

```
Mail::to($request->email)->send(new ContactMail($your_token,$link,$user));
```

and in your ContactMail class:

```
    class ContactMail extends Mailable
{
   
 use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $your_token;
    public $link;
    public $user;


public function __construct($your_token,$link,$user)
{
    $this->your_token= $your_token;
    $this->link= $link;
    $this->user= $user;
}


public function build()
{
    return $this->view('email')
        ->with('your_token',$this->your_token)
        ->with('link',$this->link)
        ->with('user',$this->user
}
```

}

Comment: How can be generated password reset link into the mail. I am not getting what will be the exact url for that.? Before sending URL i need to insert that email nd token into the password_resets table right?